# Running apache nutch in local machine

Tags: java, hadoop, web-crawler, nutch

I am trying to crawl a website using apache nutch without using map reduce or hadoop. Is this possible? and if yes how can i configure it?
Because i have kept on getting an error
ERROR o.a.n.c.Injector [main] Injector: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems

i wanted to inject the urls to a crawldb using
$ bin/nutch inject /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/nutch/apache-nutch-1.19/crawldb/ /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/nutch/apache-nutch-1.19/urls/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to run Nutch in so called "local" mode without a Hadoop cluster. Nutch includes the necessary Hadoop libraries. On Windows, however, some additional work is necessary.